# my website is not loading the CSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css

i am using 000webhost to host my website and I am using HTML and not PHP
my problem is that on my website it refuses to load the stylesheet foe the webpage so everything is messed up, however when I run the file locally on my pc everything is perfect

[a screenshot of how it is locally,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaDjS.png)

[a screenshot of the actual webpage (the hosted one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YJSb.png)

also when I check that console thing on developer mode on google chrome
[this pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGPc3.png)

it says:
Refused to apply style from 'http://ismailweb2010.000webhostapp.com/stylesheet1.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

i do not understand what it means and I think this is what is causing the problem,

here is the link of my website https://ismailweb2010.000webhostapp.com/

and here is the code of my website

index.html;

```
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
   <meta name="google-site-verification" content="T4-PmqgKoo-xEOHRUI9dZ5LaNToJ54D4b2vqx4_pS8M" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>ismail-home</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="images/favicon.png"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css">

</head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<! -- navigation --> 
<ul>
 <li><a href="https://ismaildev.itch.io/">itch.io</a></li>
 <li><a href="htmlgames.html">games</a></li>
 <li><a class="active" href="index.html">home</a></li>
 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
<! -- end of navigation -->

<h1 style="font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif">welcome to my website </h1>


<p style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">hello person this is my website <br><br>and it belongs to me</p>
<br>

<p style="font-family: 'roboto', sans-sherif;">i am a game dev, which means i make GAMES, <br>The types of games i make are, </p>

<footer>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <p>&#169; ismaildev</p>
 <br>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

about.html

```
<html lang="en-GB">

<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>ismail-about</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="images/favicon.png"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css">
</head>
<! -- navbar -->
<ul>
      <li><a href="https://ismaildev.itch.io/">itch.io</a></li>
      <li><a href="htmlgames.html">games</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
</ul>



<h1 style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">about</h1>

<p style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">its seems you have found my about page, as a reward heres what you wanted... i think</p>

<br>

<p style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">hi my name is (well you must know) and i make games, not the best at least i know how to code, </p>

<br>



<br>

<footer>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>&#169; ismaildev</p>
      <br>
</footer>
    


</body>

</html>
```

stylesheet1.css

```
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(170, 162, 162) url() no-repeat top left/5px 5px;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

header {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  50% {background: rgb(58, 52, 52) bottom right/50px 50px;}
}
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
  margin-left: 20px;
  }

/* navbar */
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


li {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}

/* Add a gray right border to all list items, except the last item (last-child) */
li {
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(88, 88, 88);
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

ul {
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #292525;
}

li a {
  color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
}

ul {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
/*end of nav bar*/

/*fonts*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  src: url(fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf);
}
/*navbar font*/
ul {
  font:15px "Arial",san-serif;
  }
```

i am kind of new to coding HTML and css so help would be appreciated

Comment: i have tried loading the website with internet explorer and edge and firefox but same things appear

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have to configure the server so it gives the browser the correct `Content-Type` header, but as you probably do not have access to the configuration files, a workaround is to set the `type` attribute of the style tags to `text/html`. That is, change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="stylesheet1.css">`.

Comment: well I have just transferred the file to the webserver and it still doesn't work however the error has disappeared and for some reason, if I open up the HTML file locally again it gets messed up as in before when I opened the file locally everything was fine but if i opened it on my webserver it was messed up, but now ever since I updated the code both of them are messed up

Comment: @ismailjamal Something is wrong with the configuration; If i open up the stylesheet directly, I get a 404 Not Found error page. You have to check the css file has the right name, and that it is in the right folder.

Comment: @ismailjamal i think you should [contact](https://www.000webhost.com/contact) the staff of 000webhost about this problem, because this cannot be fixed without knowing the directory structure on the server, etc.

Comment: @ismailjamal that the local version is messed up too is logic, because the content types are again not the same. You have to remove that again to make it work locally.

Comment: @ismailjamal i am sorry but i really cannot help you further with that, the only people who can i think is the staff at 000webhost.